# MongoDB: How to monitor time of drop command

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

How can I get a millisecond reading for the time taken to drop a collection in MongoDB (running in Ubuntu)?

I'm using '.explain' to get a reading for queries i'm executing, but when I try to tag this onto a drop command, I just get an error message:

```
 > db.Aircraft.drop().explain()
 2014-07-22T05:57:32.173-0700 TypeError: Object true has no method 'explain'
```

I get the gist of what's happening here, but I don't know of an approach to record the speed. Please can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Probably it is equal to one CPU cycle as all it does in drop() is to break the pointer link. It does not perform a zeroing out of the collection/database data.

Comment: Is there any way to issue a command that zeros out the collection data?

Comment: You can try formatting the folder (or drive, if you set up the mongo database on a separate drive altogether). In my knowledge, I don't know of anything like this. Never needed to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try running this small script...

```
use myDBName
var _start = new Date();
db.dropDatabase();
var _end = new Date();

print("Time to drop the database... " + ((_end - _start)/1000));
```

Just copy paste this in the mongo shell and if the time to drop is measurable, it will show.

Comment: I've given it a whirl - the command drops the database after the second line of the command- is this right? It's also throwing an Unexpected Token error - is there something in the print command it doesn't like?

      > var _start = new Date();
      > db.dropDatabase();
      { "dropped" : "jontestcsv", "ok" : 1 }
      > var _end = new Date();
      > print(“Time to drop the collection…”+((_end - _start)/1000));
2014-07-23T08:30:25.233-0700 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: It was the semicolon of the first line. Removed it and it works fine now. Print command is not the troublemaker.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still not working for me. I switch to the database, input the first line (without the semicolon), enter. On next line I input the drop command, enter. I get a message saying it's been dropped ok. Then I input the var _end command, enter. On the final line I input the print command, enter, then I get the syntax error. Sorry, I'm missing something obvious I'm sure. Appreciate your help.  R, Jon

Comment: You are not starting the timer? First line - choosing the db. Second - starting the timer. Third - dropping the db. Fourth - stopping the timer. Fifth - printing the time.

Comment: Also, do not enter commands manually. Copy the entire script and paste it all in one go.

Comment: Perfect - worked fantastic. Many thanks for your help and patience! R, Jon